# r: decisoin tree label doesn't show completly

Tags: r

When I am using `rpart` to draw the decision tree, there is a small problem, the label of the plot does not works well.

[image: The decision tree plot]

The plot only have a half text on the top and bottom of the plot. How can I fix this.
Here is the code:

```
library(rpart)
iris.rpart = rpart(Species ~ ., data = iris)
plot(iris.rpart) #Plot the tree
text(iris.rpart) #Show the labels
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read the documentation of `plot.rpart`, there are two options mentioned: use of the `par` option `xpd`, or using the parameter `margin` of the `plot.rpart` function.

1)
The `margin` parameter adds an extra portion of white space

```
library(rpart)
iris.rpart = rpart(Species ~ ., data = iris)
plot(iris.rpart, margin = .2)                # margin added
text(iris.rpart, use.n = T)
```

2)
Looking at your picture, it could be that `xpd` has been set to `FALSE` (see `?par`). From the documentation:

> **xpd:**  *A logical value or NA. If FALSE, all plotting is clipped to the plot
>   region, if TRUE, all plotting is clipped to the figure region, and if
>   NA, all plotting is clipped to the device region. See also clip.*

You can see the setting of `xpd` by typing:

```
par()xpd
```

in that case `xpd` is not `TRUE`, the solution is as follows:

```
opar <- par() # to reset later
par(xpd=TRUE)
plot(iris.rpart)
text(iris.rpart, use.n = T)
par <- opar # restore old setting
```

Please, let me know whether this solved your problem.